# Como alterar um item do menu depois de já criado?

Tags: java, android, menu

É o seguinte eu crio um menu através do metodo onCreateOptionsMenu,e depois eu quero deixar um item invisível porem não consigo.

```
@Override       
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_menu, menu);
    mMenu=menu
    return true;
}

@Override

 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Menu id = navigationView.getMenu();

    if (id.getItem(0) == item) {
                     //essa é a parte que eu tento deixar invisível mas ela não fica
       mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_Filtro).setVisible(false);


    }       
}
```

Comment: A pergunta não está clara. O que está a testar com `id.getItem(0) == item`?

Comment: é o seguinte ai é um fragment do drawer layout,ai quando eu abro isso eu queria tirar um item do menu que nao serve pra esse fragment.@ramaral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opá é bem simples  se pode fazer algo assim

```
boolean visible = false;

mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_Filtro).setVisible(visible);
```

quando precisar mudar a visibilidade so alterar o boleano 
e chamar esse metodo

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

se você tiver estiver em fragmento  so chamar pelo getactivity